# Convert a query to a parametised query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to convert a query into a parametised query.

My PHP/SQL query at the moment is

```
SELECT * FROM System WHERE information LIKE '%$sheet%' ORDER BY newest DESC;
```

How would I parametise this?

Comment: I guess that you refer to PHP. Google PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Is Sheet always a string?

Answer (score 2):

If `$sheet` is always a string

```
    $query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM System WHERE information LIKE ? ORDER BY newest DESC');
    $query->bindValue(1, "%$sheet%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
```

Then this should work

Comment: isn't the `LIKE` operator necessary?

Comment: @Sebas oops -- well spotted!